# How to add a udf who's parameter is a table name

Tags: apache-calcite

I want to add a udf to calcite. The udf's parameter is a table name, and it will return a varchar value. Are there any sample for this? Thanks.

My test sql is:

```
SELECT MYTEST22(a), MYTEST(a), MYTEST1(a), COUNT(*)
FROM alisis.table1 
WHERE a=max_dt(alisis.table1) 
GROUP BY MYTEST22(a),MYTEST(a),MYTEST1(a)
```

`max_dt` is the function I want to add.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your want to do, could you make a clear explanation?

No function can accept `table` as parameter, the parameters must have certain type, String, Int or others. So `constants` and `columns` can be used as parameters. If your meaning is the table name as a parameter, the sql should be as follows:

```
SELECT MYTEST22(a), MYTEST(a), MYTEST1(a), COUNT(*)
FROM alisis.table1 
WHERE a=max_dt('alisis.table1') 
GROUP BY MYTEST22(a),MYTEST(a),MYTEST1(a)
```

As I known, all functions Calcite (version is 1.11) supported are defined at `SqlStdOperatorTable`. If you want to support other functions, you can implement a class that extends `SqlStdOperatorTable`, for example:

```
public class TestOperatorTable extends SqlStdOperatorTable {
  private static volatile TestOperatorTable instance;
  public static TestOperatorTable instance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      synchronized(TestOperatorTable.class) {
        if (instance == null) {
          instance = new TestOperatorTable();
          // Use reflection to register the expressions stored in public fields.
          instance.init();
        }
      }
    }
    return instance;
  }

  /** Follow add your functions */
  public static SqlFunction LTRIM = new SqlTrimFunction("LTRIM");
}
```

`SqlTrimFunction` as follows:

```
public class SqlTrimFunction extends SqlFunction {
  public SqlTrimFunction(String funcName) {
    super(
      funcName,
      SqlKind.OTHER_FUNCTION,
      ReturnTypes.VARCHAR_2000,  // return type is String
      InferTypes.FIRST_KNOWN,
      OperandTypes.STRING,       // parameter type is String
      SqlFunctionCategory.STRING
    ); 
  }
}
```

When you create a SqlValidator, for example `SqlValidatorImpl`, you should use `TestOperatorTable` as its first parameter.

Comment: Yes, the function I want to support has the table name as a parameter. My test sql has syntax error . I will try to implement the class . Thank you very mach!

Comment: @fei.chen https://stackoverflow.com/a/44962144/1314077 this may be helpful to add UDF, do not extend SqlStdOperatorTable.